# Wordpress and Subscriber levels

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone know how to create 3 different subscriber levels? 
Level 1 would have access to all pages defined as A
Level 2 would have access to all pages defined as B
Level 3 would have access to all pages A & B

I was thinking I could do this with user roles and capabilities, but am not clear on how I can create different subscribers.

I'm hoping to avoid using a plugin because I'd like to keep this as simple as possible.

Thank you!
Michael

Comment: Why would you want to avoid a plugin? They are usually very simple and have reviews so you know which ones are easy to use.

Comment: The main reason is that 2member pro is expensive. I'm also wanting to add this functionality to a custom shopping cart plugin I'm building, so I didn't want to be dependent on another plugin. However, if you can recommend a free plugin that I could mimic functionality, that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this and keep it simple is to add a meta_key to user_meta. The user_key will be member and have an array of values. In my output I'll check first if the user has a role of subscriber. Then I'll check the value of the user_meta - member. This will determine what the user sees.